# Why do I get unhandled promise rejection in this situation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have the next function in my code that can interrupt execution due to several reasons:

```
const getAndCheckItem = async (itemId) => {
    try {
        const item = await getItem(itemId);
        if(item.firstFail) {
            throw "First fail";
        }
        if(item.secondFail) {
            throw "Second fail";
        }
        if(notGood(item)) {
            throw "Third fail"; 
        }

        return item;
    }
    catch(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

If I call it inside some other async function in the following way, everything is fine and any internal throw is handled:

```
try {
    item = await getAndCheckItem(ids[0]);
}
catch(err) {
    // handle error
}
```

However, when I call the function for several ids:

```
try {
    items = await Promise.all([ids.map(value => getAndCheckItem(value))]);
}
catch(err) {
    // handle error
}
```

I receive unhandled promise reject in case of any internal throw. I understand that Promise.all() considers any returned non-promise value as a resolved promise. However, `Promise.reject(err)` should return a Promise and thus be handled. What's the problem?

Comment: Try removing the square brackets on `ids.map`. `map()` already returns an array

Comment: @CristopherNamchee Thank you, sir! I've spent several hours to locate the error, read articles and change my understanding of the Universe, but as usual, looked into the wrong place. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Promise.all() considers any returned non-promise value as a resolved promise.

Sure, but when you do

```
return Promise.reject(err);
```

you're returning a Promise, so once it gets unwrapped by the caller, the `getAndCheckItem` call results in a rejected Promise. Doing `return Promise.reject(err)` is very similar to doing `throw err` inside something `async`.

If all you do in a `catch` is re-throw or return a rejected Promise, there's not much point to it - you may as well leave that part off completely, and just let the caller handle it:

```
const getAndCheckItem = async (itemId) => {
  const item = await getItem(itemId);
  if(item.firstFail) {
    throw "First fail";
  }
  if(item.secondFail) {
    throw "Second fail";
  }
  if(notGood(item)) {
    throw "Third fail"; 
  }
  return item;
}
```

You're also currently passing an *array of arrays* of Promises to `Promise.all`:

```
await Promise.all([ids.map(value => getAndCheckItem(value))]);
```

In which case the `Promise.all` won't really do anything, since the only item of its array is a non-Promise (another array). If any of the *inner* promises reject, they won't be handled, so you'll get an unhandled rejection.

Instead, pass an array of Promises to `Promise.all`:

```
await Promise.all(ids.map(value => getAndCheckItem(value)));
```

Or, more concisely:

```
await Promise.all(ids.map(getAndCheckItem));
```